# Where can I buy fake ears/pinnae to use with binaural in-ear microphones?

Tags: binaural

I have a pair of in-ear binaural mics (Roland CS-10EM), and I'd like to make binaural recordings without them being attached to my ears. Is there anywhere I can get (or make) a pair of fake ears to use them with?

Answer (score 1):

I was mildly surprised that this was the first Google result...
http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ear-model

Comment: This is what happens when you search for things with *sensible* keywords!

Answer (score 1):

I made these specifically to improve the quality of DIY binaural microphones.
https://www.shapeways.com/shops/binaural-microphone-ears

Answer (score 1):

Ears for acupuncture training are not bad and cheap.

(random example)
https://www.anatomywarehouse.com/acupuncture-right-ear-model-a-100064
[image]